# How to show Qr Code in Kendo Grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, qr-code

This is my div but it outside kendo grid

```
<div>
<div id="qrUrl"></div> 
</div>
```

This is my kendo grid field

```
 columns: [
    {
     field: "Id",
    },
    {
    title: "QrCode",
    width: 300,
    template: function(dataItem) 
    {     
       $(#Qrurl).kendoQRCode({ 
       value: "www.google.com"+ dataItem.Id,
       errorCorrection: "M",
       size: 120,
       border: {
       color: "#000000",
       width: 5
               }
       });
    }
```

In this situation my Qrcode generated outside grid with uniq **(url+id )**
but i want to this all qrcode in my kendo grid.

i tried servel time this and another code but still not reached up to mark.

```
 template: function(dataItem) 
        {     
           $('<div></div>')
           .kendoQRCode({ 
           value: "www.google.com"+ dataItem.Id,
           errorCorrection: "M",
           size: 120,
           border: {
           color: "#000000",
           width: 5
                   }
           });
        }
```

If i tried with div id at that time i got qrcodes as per requirement but outside grid here, i want to complete this thing in my grid.

Please help me.

Thank you for advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The template function needs to return a string of the HTML that will be used. I would have the template create an empty DIV in the grid cell with a class="QRME" and a data attribute for the id. Then in the dataBound event of the grid, loop through all the QRME divs, get the id and create the QR codes:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [   {
     field: "Id",
    }, {
    title: "QrCode",
    width: 300,
    template: function(dataItem) {
      return "<div class='QRME' data-id='" + kendo.htmlEncode(dataItem.Id) + "'></div>";
    }
  }],
  dataSource: [ { Id: "1" }, { Id: "2" }, { Id: "3" }  ],
  dataBound: function(e) {
    $("div.QRME").each(function(idx){
         $(this).kendoQRCode({ 
         value: "www.google.com"+ $(this).data("id"),
         errorCorrection: "M",
         size: 120,
         border: {
            color: "#000000",
            width: 5
         }
       });
    });
  }
});
```

## Working **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/uCUzO)**

Comment: Mr. Ezanker Thank you for your response.i tried to solve this issue with last two days but you solved within a minute.

Answer (score 1):

I can't use dataBound and therefore I was looking for a solution that works with template.
First I make a div instance and put the QR code there and return outerHTML.

```
template: function(dataItem) {
  return jQuery("<div class='qrcode'></div>")
          .kendoQRCode({
          value: kendo.htmlEncode(dataItem["Id"]),
          errorCorrection: "M",
          size: 60,
          border: {
            color: "#000",
            width: 1
          }
        }).html();
}
```

## working [DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/iCePusAz/5)

Comment: This variant only needs template code and can also be edited and after editing the QR code will be re-rendered. 
In the demo example PDF Export was integrated.
But the big disadvantage is that the QR code does not appear in the PDF.


Does anyone have an idea why this is so?

Comment: QR-Code appears in pdf with latest version "2022.1.301"